# Sharing data between 2 Android applications

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, ipc

I have gone through a lot of similar answers, but since a lot of things have changed recently, I wanted to ask it again.

I have an application A that stores data in Shared Preferences. I want application B to be able to access the data stored in the Shared Preferences by application A.

Findings so far -

- We can't use **WORLD_READABLE** for Shared Preferences, since it has
  been deprecated.
- We can't use **sharedUserId** to share data since it has been
  deprecated.
- I also read that apps signed with the same key can access each
  other's code and data. But can we access the data just by doing that?
  (Or do we need to do something else also along with the signing
  process?). If yes, how?

One of the solutions is to share the data using Content Providers (data source being the Shared Preferences).
Are there any other ways to share the data as well?

Answer (score 0):

> I also read that apps signed with the same key can access each other's code and data

Only via `sharedUserId`.

> Are there any other ways to share the data as well?

You could:

- Have one app expose a service that the other app starts and passes the data via `Intent` extras
- Have one app expose a service that the other app binds to and passes the data via AIDL parameters
- Have one app send an explicit broadcast `Intent` to the other app with the data included in `Intent` extras
- Have one app start an activity in the other app with the data included in `Intent` extras

Those options, as with the `ContentProvider` solution, can be secured by Android's permission system. If you carefully set up a custom permission, with a `protectionLevel` of `signature`, those apps will be able to communicate with each other, but other apps will not be able to hack into those communication channels.

And, of course, another option is to just have one app.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In all the 4 solutions mentioned above, the flow starts from the app that wants to share the data, kindly correct me if I am wrong. My use case it to access the data already stored by the other app, the Content Provider allows me to do that. My use case is basically a SSO implementation to access token and other details.

Comment: @KashishMalhotra If its for account data, have you considered AccountManager?  https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/custom_auth

Comment: @KashishMalhotra: "In all the 4 solutions mentioned above, the flow starts from the app that wants to share the data, kindly correct me if I am wrong" -- the second one (binding to a service) is more of a "pull" mechanism rather than "push", which seems to be what you want.

Comment: @GabeSechan Thank you for the suggestion, I went through it. We already have an app that is live, and we want to make another app live and use the SSO. Since most of the users will already be logged-in into the first app, we won't be able to create a custom account using the first application, correct?

Comment: Also, I was wondering how companies like Amazon achieve SSO with their applications, I couldn't find it anywhere. They don't have a custom account listed, so my best guess is that those apps are sharing data between them. CMIIW. It would be great if someone can point me to some related resources.